# imprimir o maior número

Tags: python

Tenho que criar um programa em Python que imprime o maior número entre dois fornecidos e gostaria de saber se existe uma solução mais simples do que a que eu usei (sem usar a conta X-Y, por exemplo):

```
X = float(input("Digite um valor para X: "))
Y = float(input("Digite um valor para Y: "))
    
if X - Y < 0:
    print ("O maior valor é", Y)
else:
    print ("O maior valor é", X)
```

Comment: O que quer dizer ou considera como *"....uma solução mais simples do que a que eu usei..."*? Qual a finalidade da linha `maior_valor = 0`?

Comment: esqueci de apagar essa linha. Sobre a solução, queria saber se há algum modo de chegar no mesmo resultado sem a conta x - y

Comment: Para que replicar esse resultado? Você deveria estar procurando melhorar. O código não consegue distinguir quando duas entradas são iguais e o limite de precisão é baixo.

Comment: foi pedido do professor não distinguir se as duas entradas são iguais. Sobre o resto, fiquei apenas curiosa se havia outra saída para o problema.

Comment: obrigada por ajudar muito viu

Comment: Não precisa subtrair, basta fazer `if X > Y: print('maior é', X) else: print('maior é', Y)`

Comment: Alterando o código do @hkotsubo para visualizar a saída: `if X > Y:` `print('O maior valor está em X:', X)` `else: print('O maior valor está em Y:', Y)` (é a mesma coisa, só acrescentei o nome da variável no texto do print para visualizar de onde pegou o número como uma forma até de debugar o código) - o que inclusive ajuda a revelar o problema da igualdade. Lembrando que tem outras várias maneiras de fazer, incluindo por o if na linha do print.

Comment: Seja como for, lembre-se de em próximas perguntas além do enunciado ser mais específica na dúvida, por exemplo de forma bem sucinta explicar como chegou na conclusão e qual a dificuldade - até porque, sem parâmetros o "mais simples" acaba sendo opinião pessoal. Com mais parâmetros para entender o problema, em vez de alguém simplesmente propor resposta para o exercício (que nao é bem o [objetivo do site](/help)), as respostas podem ajudar a ensinar programação de fato não só para você como para futuros visitantes.

Comment: o mundo não vai acabar porque fiz uma pergunta entre as milhares do site, gente. era uma dúvida real minha!! muito obrigada aos que ajudaram :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução mais direta é o método max(), presente na linguagem como palavra reservada (não precisa importar nada para a utilizar) e que retorna o maior para iteráveis ou múltiplos argumentos.

Neste caso você poderia fazer apenas

```
X = float(input("Digite um valor para X: "))
Y = float(input("Digite um valor para Y: "))
           
print ("O maior valor é", max(X,Y))
```

Consulte mais sobre o método Max aqui:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Ele aceita vários argumentos, então você poderia passar `max(X,y,z,s)` que ele retornaria o maior, da mesma forma.

Pode passar também iteráveis (se somente um elemento for passado como argumento, é obrigatório que seja iterável, como listas e tuplas

```
maior= max ([X,Y,Z])
```

Comment: entendi!! é uma boa forma também, obrigada :)